# invalid rfc 3339 timestamp format?

Tags: google-data-api, rfc3339

I inserted this timestamp as part of the blogger query:

> http://www.blogger.com/feeds/26861498/posts/default?published-min=1937-01-01T12:00:27.87+08:00

It returned me an invalid pub-min format error.

But as far as I know, this time format looks alright!

can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Morever, I can use sometihng like '12:22:00-07:00' but just not '+08:00'*

Very simple error you've made: not URI-encoding the value. You see, `+` is actually a space in a URI, and won't reach the server as a plus unless you encode it as `%2B`. Use the PHP function `rawurlencode` or the JavaScript function `encodeURIComponent` to escape the argument before sending.